# jQuery ui accordion - different collapse panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I couldn't quite find what I was looking for on other questions so here goes.

Here is my code for an accordion using jQuery UI

```
    $('.blog-m-post').accordion({
      header: "h3",
      active: "true"
    });
```

My problem is that the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header) state

> Content panels must be the sibling immediately after their associated
>   headers.

But with my markup, the content panel isn't immediately after the header, but one after that.

Example:

```
<div class="blog-m-post">
  <h3>My blog post title</h3>

  <div class="foo"> <!-- this becomes the collapsed element -->
    <p>Posted on: 8th Aug</p> <p>Author: John Doe</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content"> <!-- but I want THIS to collapse instead -->
    <p>my content inside here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the `.content` be the collapsable element as currently, it is `.foo` ?

The `.foo` **needs to stay where it is** in terms of ordering as it needs to be shown by default. `.content` is where the inner content will be that should collapse and open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `<div class="foo"></div>` inside a HEADER-div and 
keep the `<div class="content">` as immediate sibling of that HEADER.

For example:

```
 <div class="blog-m-post">
      <div class="header">
        <h3>My blog post title</h3>
        <div class="foo"> <!-- this becomes the collapsed element -->
          <p>Posted on: 8th Aug</p> <p>Author: John Doe</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content"> <!-- but I want THIS to collapse instead -->
        <p>my content inside here</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

and the JQuery would be:

```
$('.blog-m-post').accordion({
      header: "div.header",
      active: "true"
});
```

[Here is the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onjconLw/2/)

Comment: Works great only it doesn't re-collapse back up?

Comment: @AshleyBrown Thats what accordion is. However there are certain config options. Just add "collapsible: true" to achieve that. Check this updated Fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/onjconLw/3/

Answer (score 1):

As [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) state:

> The markup of your accordion container needs pairs of headers and
>   content panels

and also (as you already know)

> Content panels must be the sibling immediately after their associated
>   headers.

So you have to pair each header with the associated content to make it/them collapsible. Having an extra element inside the accordion and always visible requires quite a hack and I would suggest using toggle instead. Anyway, in accordion a solution would be to append the extra content after the creation and when activate remove it, refresh and append again. Ultimately, something like that:

```js
$('.blog-m-post').accordion({
      header: "h3",
      active: "true",
      collapsible: true,      
      create: function(){
          $('h3').after('<div class="extra content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active"><div class="foo">Foo content here</div></div>');        
      },
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.extra').remove();
        $( ".blog-m-post" ).accordion( "refresh" );
        if(ui.newHeader.length==1){//open
          $('.foo').remove();
          $('.content').prepend('<div class="foo">Foo content here</div>')        
        }else{
          $('h3').after('<div class="extra content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active"><div class="foo">Foo content here</div></div>');    
        }    
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="blog-m-post">
  
  <h3>Accordion</h3>
  
  <div class="content">
    <p>my content inside here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unsure as to what type of answer that is... it's not really an answer is it.  I'm aware of what the docs say, the whole point in this post is to try and get around the default behavior.

Comment: Updated the answer, check out how `collapsible: true` or `toggle()` can suit your needs in case the given snippet is not a good fit.

Comment: No because as I stated in the question, `.foo` has to stay in it's current order.  It's supposed to be like: Title -> post meta (Author, date posted, number of comments) -> collapsed/expand panel. Essentially, my current markup will place the date, author and "likes" the post has, underneath the title. This accordion is for like a blog post.

Comment: You're right Asley, see how `activate` can be used to achieve this in my updated answer

Comment: That's a great answer. Unfortunately I actually have PHP running in some parts of the `.foo` in a loop to output that data. The whole accordion is within a blog post loop actually. Your explanation would work, but appending/prepending won't work for what I have but that's my fault for not mentioning the php.